# How to deal with system Python and `brew link python` on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I cannot link Python 3.8 over system Python 3.9.

I have few installed python versions (3.8, 3.10, etc) by brew and system Python 3.9.

P.S. I cannot uninstall system one (it does not appear in Applications).

```bash
$ python3 --version                                
Python 3.10.9

$ brew unlink python@$(python3 --version | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'); brew link python@3.8
Unlinking /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9... 25 symlinks removed.
Warning: Already linked: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.16
To relink, run:
  brew unlink python@3.8 && brew link python@3.8

$ python3 --version                                                                        
Python 3.9.6

$ type python3                                               
python3 is /usr/bin/python3

 $ python3[press TAB]
python3            python3-config     python3.10         python3.10-config  python3.11         python3.11-config

$ python3.8 --version
zsh: command not found: python3.8

 $ echo $PATH
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Questions:

1. How to set brewed Python over system one?
2. <s>How to uninstall system python?</s> (not recommended)
3. How to link `python` in addition to `python3`?
4. <s>Why there is no `python3.8` available?</s> (solved with `brew reinstall python@3.8`)

**UPD:**

4. `python3.8` became available after `brew reinstall python@3.8`.

**UPD 2:**

It looks like there is no way to fix this properly. Must be a bug of 3.8 installer.

Here is workaround commands:

```bash
mkdir ~/bin/
ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3.8 ~/bin/python
chmod u+x,og-rwx ~/bin/python
```

And this `~/bin` to your `PATH`.

@micromoses described the same in Method #4.

Comment: #2: Don't. Leave the system-installed version for Apple to delete or upgrade.

Comment: Is it alright now?

Comment: @tadman, no, still `brew link` does not work for 3.8. `python3` stays the same - system python.

Comment: You should check the precedence in your `PATH`. If your Homebrew path isn't ahead, it'll end up getting bumped.

Comment: @tadman, but it does work for `python@3.10` for some reason.

Comment: Maybe they fixed something in an older brew recipe. If you want a really specific Python version it's often best to just pop open a Docker container, that's a lot easier than installing, linking and unlinking different versions or even using something like `pyenv`, especially for really old versions.

Comment: Well, added sample of PATH. `brew` dir ahead of all. Yeah, it's clear with Docker way.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How to set brewed Python over system one?

All you need to do is prepend `/opt/homebrew/bin` to the beginning of your path. Your `$PATH` variable seems to be correctly set, so if it is not working I'd try restarting your terminal.

If all else fails, you can also explicitly prepend `/opt/homebrew/opt/python@VERION_NUMBER/bin` to the beginning of your path.

> 3. How to link python in addition to python3?

If you run `brew info python`, Homebrew tells you this caveat:

> Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
> `python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
> /opt/brew/opt/python@3.10/libexec/bin

So, all you need to do is prepend `/opt/brew/opt/python@VERSION_NUMBER/libexec/bin` to the beginning of your path. Just add this line to the end of your zshrc, bashrc, or equivalent:

```
export PATH="/opt/brew/opt/python@VERSION_NUMBER/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

This will make all the unversioned Python utils available to you.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is best to avoid directly overriding (modifying) symbolic or hard links pointing to the system's python version. These might be used by system functions/scripts which are (hopefully) tested against that specific python binary. Changing the version (especially downgrading, but sometimes even upgrading) can break things for the OS.
2. For the same reason stated above, uninstalling/deleting the system's python should also be avoided.
3. I struggled myself with MacOS not having `python` as an executable, so I'll focus my answer on that.
4. Looks like you already found a way to resolve that.

---

I can think of 4 ways to get a `python` executable;

#### Method #1 - probably not what you want

The *easy* way to make `python` available in (z)shell on mac is to add an alias:

```
echo "alias python=python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

With this, in all new zsh sessions (or where `.zshrc` is reloaded), running `python` will run the `python3` executable in your PATH. You can also set the alias's target to be a full path, so point it to the python version you like (if, for example, one is installed using homebrew). There are two problems: changing the target requires reloading `.zshrc`, and this will only take effect when executing python from an open shell (will not work for executable scripts/entrypoints - more on that later).

#### Method #2 - optimal for homebrew

Unversioned `python`, `pip` and other such symlinks are installed in `libexec/bin` directories of brew packages. If you are using homebrew you can add these to your path, like so:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3/libexec/bin"' >> .zprofile
```

As homebrew uses symlinks for package versioning, you can replace `python@3` in the above example with a more explicit version (e.g. `python@3.8` or `python@3.10`).

#### Method #3 - requires admin privileges

If you have admin privileges, you can add a symlink in your path to the executable, like so (change `/usr/bin/python3` to the brew's python executable you like):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

While hardlinks will work as well, I recommend avoiding them as there might be a chance that it will negatively affect minor version upgrades by keeping the older executable (haven't tested myself).
The upside of this method is that it will probably work for all users and all applications, as it is extremely rare for applications to not include `/usr/local/bin` in the execution search path.

#### Method #4 - intermediary executable

This (much like method #2) probably won't work for applications that are not invoked by (z)shell (possibly your favorite IDE), but it is most flexible, and does not require admin privileges. It entails adding an intermediary binary, and adding that to your PATH. I usually create a `bin` directory in my homedir for such occasions, so I'll use that path in the examples. First, create the executable:

```
mkdir ~/bin
echo '#!/bin/sh\nexec /usr/bin/python3 "$@"' > ~/bin/python
chmod +x ~/bin/python
```

Now add `~/bin` to your shell's path:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"' >> .zprofile
```

*Alternatively*, `.zshrc` or `.zshenv` can be used, but additional precaution has to be taken to avoid repeatedly adding `~/bin` to the path in subshells:

```
echo '_home_bindir="$HOME/bin"\n[ "${PATH##*:}" = "$_home_bindir" ] || export PATH="$PATH:$_home_bindir"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Now, every new shell (or if using `.zshrc` - if it is reloaded) will have `python` executable in its path, and you can easily edit the file to point to your favorite python version.

---

#### Notes:

Method #2 is probably the best option if using homebrew, which is the case in question. Still, as I struggled with not having a `python` executable on a "clean" MacOS installation (without homebrew), I've added methods #1, #3, and #4, in case I'm not the only one *not* using homebrew's python.

Methods #2, #3, and #4, allow for executable scripts/entrypoints. By that, I'm referring to executable scripts with shebang, most commonly using the `env` executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

These 3 methods will also honor additional python arguments (e.g. `python -u`).

As MacOS no longer comes with a `python` executable (only `python3`), I think that method #3 is fairly safe to use (at least from a perspective of not breaking OS scripts). As for `$PATH` manipulation, I wouldn't recommend prepending it with user-writeable paths (like `~/bin`), as this may lead to a security issue, or worse - a debugging nightmare (of course, no one would ever create executables like `~/bin/ls` or `~/bin/which`, right?).

As for the specific shell, this will also work for bash by changing the relevant files (`.z..` to `.bash..`) as long as the profile/rc files are properly loaded. For other shells (e.g. `tcsh`) the syntax needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It looks like it's a dead end to have any python 3.* linked to `python3` properly. It's a pity, it must be a bug or something. So, 1) is not resolved. Yes, I don't need to uninstall system one, but I was curious.

Comment: So, once I got `python3.8` I decided to link it to `~/bin/python` like you mentioned in #4.

Comment: By the way,  option #1, yes, I don't use it, as it does not work in some cases for bash scripts. bin-folders only =)